# Can we use different values of PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS for tow different links?

Tags: python, django

Django uses a setting `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS` whose default value is **3 Days**. In my code, I am using reset password functionality of Django also as One Time Link (just like One time password) to set the password for the user upon registration.

But this link also has the same expiry duration i.e. **3 Days**

Can I do something which will increase its expiry duration but doesn't mess with the default reset password functionality of my app?

Something like `override_settings` which we use in unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Sharing it here in case anybody faces the same issue can follow the same method to resolve the problem

Actually, I used a context manager to switch between two different values of the settings.

```
from django.conf import settings


class one_time_password_link_expiry:
    """
    It's a context manager, responsible to set different expiry durations
    for reset password link and one time password link.
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.last_login = kwargs['last_login']
        self.default_timeout = kwargs['default_timeout']

    def __enter__(self):
        """
        If user have never logged in to the system, we will change
        the expiry duration of reset password link.
        """
        if not self.last_login:
            settings.PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS = settings.OTP_LINK_TIMEOUT

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        """
        Revert to the original settings.
        """
        settings.PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS = self.default_timeout
```

Using the value of `last_login` attribute of `User` object, I identify that either the user is coming on our platform for the first time or it is the normal reset password reset request.

You may need to write a `wrapper` around Django's default password reset view to use this context manager like this [edx-platform code](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/blob/open-release/ironwood.master/common/djangoapps/student/views/management.py#L833).

```
def password_reset_confirm_wrapper(request, uidb36=None, token=None):
    """
    A wrapper around django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm.
    Needed because we want to set the user as active at this step.
    We also optionally do some additional password policy checks.
    """
    ...
    ...
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        ...
        with one_time_password_link(last_login=user.last_login, default_settings=settings.PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS):
            response = password_reset_confirm(
                request, uidb64=uidb64, token=token, extra_context=platform_name
            )
        ...
        ...
    else:
        ...
        ...
        with one_time_password_link(last_login=user.last_login, default_settings=settings.PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS):
            response = password_reset_confirm(
                request, uidb64=uidb64, token=token, extra_context=platform_name
            )
        ...
        ...

    return response
```